# Reducing wave equation to laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Question: I want t reduce the following wave equation $$u_n=c^2(u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz})$$ to Laplace equation $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}+u_{\tau\tau}=0$$ by letting $\tau=ict$ and $i$ is imaginary. And I want to obtain the solution of wave equation in cylindrical coordinates via the solution of the Laplace equation. Assuming that $u(r,\theta,z,\tau)$ is independent of $z$.

Approach: I took $c^2={\tau^2}/{-t^2}$ and plugged it into this weird wave equation $u_n$. When I took the derivative $u_{\tau\tau}$ and tried finding the Laplace equation. I got it but for $t=\sqrt2$. After that I'm not sure how I am I supposed to solve this using the cylindrical coordinates for wave equation or Laplace equation. I would be grateful if anyone can atleast give me a direction! thank you

P.S The question was posed as it is in the Linear PDE by Myint-U and Debnath.

Comment: What is $u_n$ ?

Comment: that's what's confusing me.. as I wrote it exactly from the textbook.

Comment: Probably just a typo. The PDE to be actual wave equation it should be $u_{tt}$ there.

Comment: exactly!!. But I'm still confused as to how am I going to plug in $\tau$?? and then finding the solution i only need he laplace right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's a typo there, and it's actually 
$$
u_{tt} = c^2 \left( u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz}\right )
$$
one can do the following (as mentioned in your textbook) $\tau = i ct$, so
\begin{align}
u_t &= u_{\tau} \tau_t = ic u_\tau \\
u_{tt} &= \left( u_t\right )_t = \left(ic u_\tau \right )_\tau \tau_t = i^2 c^2 u_{\tau \tau} = -c^2 u_{\tau \tau}
\end{align}
Substitute it to the wave equation
$$
-c^2 u_{\tau \tau} = c^2 \left( u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz}\right ) \implies u_{\tau \tau} + u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz} = \Delta u= 0
$$
which is Laplace equation in $4$ dimensions $x,y,z,\tau$.

Comment: But this laplace I have to solve in 3D right?? Because u is independent of z??

Comment: @d13, nope it's fully 4 dimensional equation now. It might not depend on $z$, but it should be some additional constraint, which is not there as it is right now.

Comment: how am I supposed to solve it using cylindrical coordinates?? especially when it has $\tau$ in it.

Comment: @d13 You may look to [this](http://www.physics.usu.edu/riffe/3750/Lecture%2021.pdf) paper. But if in short, method is the same – separation of variables.

Comment: thankyou Sir!! I appreciate your help and advice!!! you made my day. :))